# How to add miliseconds to datetime object

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, milliseconds

I need to convert seconds to `HH:mm:ss:ms` format. My fucntion as below.

```
 function formatTime(time) {
        var rootDate = new Date(new Date(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).setSeconds(time));
        console.log(rootDate);
        return rootDate;
 }

 formatTime(100);
```

the above function gives following output,

```
Thu Feb 01 2018 00:01:40 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

you can see, it returns time as `00:01:40`. But I need the milliseconds part as well. like `00:01:40:00` How can I do it.

**I need to return datatime object**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with setMilliseconds function like

```
function formatTime(time) {
    var rootDate = new Date(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    rootDate.setMilliseconds(time); 
    console.log(rootDate);
    return rootDate;
```

}

formatTime(100);

Comment: yes, its shows `Thu Feb 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` as outpout